# How to read from XML file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, angularjs

When I run [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2) in Chrome on my machine it does not display the table. I have saved the required XML file and this source file in the same folder. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's console? And why have you added the "angularjs" tag to the question? (Also, it's best to show the relevant code directly in your question.)

Comment: How is this related to angularjs? Where have you saved the required XML file?

Comment: After conversion i want to use data extracted from XML in angular js ng-grid , and then i want to perform various tasks on it